# I need to randomize a number between two hex numbers, represented as strings

Tags: c++

...and return the number as string.

How can I do that? Is there any library for that?

Comment: So you have two strings:  "0x0001" and "0xffff" and you want to convert those to ints, then choose a random number between them.  Is that correct?

Comment: eriks seems to have some disorder that prevents him from providing the necessary information in his questions - either that or he is simply too lazy to do so.

Comment: Probably to lazy.
Sorry for that - i am trying to make my questions as clear as possible (without any success, obviously).

Comment: @eriks The best way to provide the information we need is to give an EXAMPLE of what you are asking about.

Comment: OK - will try to provide examples from now on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `std::istringstring` from `<sstream>` to convert the strings to integers. Then you can use `rand` or `random` to get a random number, which you can constrain to the interval using modular arithmetic, and then you can convert the number to a hexadecimal string using `std::ostringstream`.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int hexstr2int(const std::string& str)
{
    int result;
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    iss >> result;
    return result;
}

std::string int2hexstr(int number)
{
   std::ostringstream oss;
   oss << std::hex << number;
   return number.str();
}

int randint(int lower, int upper)
{
     int range = upper - lower;
     return ((rand()%range)+lower);
}

std::string randhexstr(const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
{
    int lower = hexstr2int(a);
    int upper = hexstr2int(b);
    return int2hexstr(randint(lower,upper));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

boost::lexical_cast is pretty useful and convenient for converting between strings and numbers.  It lets you write expressions like:

```
int some_number = boost::lexical_cast<int>(some_string);
```

or the other way:

```
std::string some_string = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(some_int);
```

Comment: Just remember to catch bad_lexical_casts

Answer (score 0):

My reply isn't going to be as useful as others, but this is really a basic programming problem.

Learning to program consists in some way in learning how to break problems into subproblems, up to a point where the small problem is manageable.

You want to randomize a number between two hex numbers, represented as strings.

The starting point here is that you want a random number. Finding out how to get a random number shouldn't be that complicated.

Now perhaps the random number function you have doesn't accept a range.

Say for example it produces floating numbers between 0 and 1, you want numbers between a and b. It's not hard to find you can convert a number n from 0 - 1 to a number m from a - b : `m = n*(b-a)+a`
Sometimes you'll have a random function that gives an integer number between 0 and the given argument; sometimes it'll be different -- apply the same reasoning.

Then you need to find the a and b values for your range, but you have strings representing hex numbers. Well you'll obviously will have to find a way to convert them to decimal numbers. It shouldn't be hard to find a function that does that for you. If you don't, parsing a hex string isn't that hard.

And voilà. By breaking the problem into subproblems, you managed to find your way to the solution.

Comment: Would the downvoter be kind and polite and leave a comment explaining his reason ? Thanks.